# Callback when Component gets on / off screen from Navigator

Tags: react-native

Is there any callbacks to rendered components from the Navigator when a view gets on / off screen?

Answer (score 2):

In the `renderScene()` method, you can pass a prop like `isRendered={route.index === 0}` for the first card, `isRendered={route.index === 1}` for the second, etc.

And then in the components themselves, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
  const { isRendered } = this.props
  if (isRendered && !next.isRendered) // going off screen
  if (!isRendered && next.isRendered) // coming on screen
}
```